# How to get the Slider value with useRef

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to avoid re-rendering the Slider component every time the `Slider` changes, so I want to use `useRef` instead of `useState`. How can I access the value of the slider with `useRef`? Logging `ref.current` is a bunch of nested `spans` with no `value` attribute, so I can't log `ref.current.value`.

[Link to material-ui docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-slider/)

```
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Stack from "@mui/material/Stack";
import Slider from "@mui/material/Slider";
import VolumeDown from "@mui/icons-material/VolumeDown";
import VolumeUp from "@mui/icons-material/VolumeUp";

export default function SliderInput() {
  console.log("Rendering slider input");

  const sliderRef = React.useRef();

  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: 200 }}>
      <Stack spacing={2} direction="row" sx={{ mb: 1 }} alignItems="center">
        <VolumeDown />
        <Slider
          ref={sliderRef}
          aria-label="Volume"
          defaultValue={30}
          valueLabelDisplay="auto"
        />
        <VolumeUp />
      </Stack>
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        onClick={() => console.log(sliderRef.current)}
      >
        Console Log Color
      </Button>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The slider is an HTML element that contains 3 `span` elements.

The value is determined by the width of the second span element.

You can print the inline CSS styles of the second child span element in the slider to print its width.

```js
console.log(sliderRef.current.children[1].style.cssText);
```

This will print `left: 0%; width: 47%;`.

If you want to get the width percentage you can use `regex` to extract the percentage from this text.

```js
const text = sliderRef.current.children[1].style.cssText; // the inline styles
const width = text.match(/width: (\d+%)/); // getting width value
console.log(width[1]); // width percentage
```